# Display value returned by function in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component `Field.jsx`.

```
class Field extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
```

players is a list of dicts which contains structures like so:

```
[{"name": "Edson", "position": "Forward"}...{...}, {...}]
```

And I have created this function to filter a list of dicts so as to display all players names based on a position:

```
getPlayersByPosition = (players, position) => {
    return players.filter((player) => player.position === 'Forward');
  }
```

And here I'm trying to display the first player 'name' returned by the function directly `<Position> HERE </Position>`, with:

```
render() {
    const { players } = this.props;
    if(players){
      return (
       <div className="back">
          <div className="field-wrapper">
            <Output output={this.props} />
            <div className="row">
              <Position>
               {this.getPlayersByPosition(players, 'Forward')[0]}> //does not work
              </Position>
              <Position> 
               {players[1].name} //works
              </Position>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
  }else{
    return null}
  }
}
```

---

On my first `<Position>`, when I try to apply the function, I'm getting:

[image]

On the second I get the value printed:

[image]

---

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your `getPositionData` function makes no sense. You don't use the `val` parameter at all, and you set the `players` state value to *itself*, which does nothing. In addition, the way you're passing the filtered players to the `handleClick` via `props.children` is very unusual, definitely not the React way. Also, calling `getPlayersByPosition(players, name)` will return an *array* of player objects, whereas `players[1].name` just returns a single string, so the 2 aren't equivalent in any way.

Comment: It's hard to give advice since there isn't any 1 major thing wrong, but a good start would be simply passing in the filtered list of position players to the Position component as a prop, and then the Position component can just render them.

Comment: I'm learning...I know they are not equivalent...But I need to return the string using the first approach. Could you please be so kind to fix what I'm doing wrong in the function?

Comment: Forget `getPositionData`. it's not really relavant to the problem here, apart from being handled on click. it works on console, by the way. The issue here is getting the string from the function and displaying it.

Comment: If you clarify getPlayersByPosition() I’ll certainly accept and upvote it

Comment: Ok so what do you want returned from that function, just the first 4 characters of the name of the person who was passed in? E.g. `getPlayersByPosition(players, 'Edson')` return `"Edso"`. Or are you wanting an array of the first 4 player objects that match that name (which is what it currently does)?

Comment: I just need the item retrieved from the dict based on any given condition. Not the array. One single item. you can forget about the slice.

Comment: @Jayce444 sorry Jayce, please refer to my edit. I've made myself more clear now.

Comment: and if you are trying to answer, please do not apply map() to `<Position>`. this will mess the css structure. I just need the first result `[0]` from the function inplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in React objects are not valid as a children. so when you are trying to render

```
{this.getPlayersByPosition(players, 'Forward')[0]}
```

it is returning the first object from the filtered array .
if you do something like

```
{this.getPlayersByPosition(players, 'Forward')[0].name}
```

it should work